# How to join string characters one by one if both string are not same in length using core python 3 only

Tags: python

**I am beginner in python and i am working on a small task to join two string character by character 
without using any predefined function especially when string are not same in length**

**for ex: s1 = 'MICROSOFT', s2 = 'CORPS' then output will be >> MC IO CR RP OS SOFT**

**I have written below code**

```
s1 = 'MICROSOFT'
s2 = 'CORPS'

for i in range(len(s1) and len(s2)):
    if len(s1)==len(s2):
       var = s1[i] + s2[i]
       print(var , end='')
    elif len(s1)!=len(s2):
        if len(s1)>len(s2):
           var1 = s1[i] + s2[i]
           print(var1, end=' ')
```

**By using above code i have achieved output like this: MC IO CR RP OS**

**How i can print the last part i.e SOFT??**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this after your loop

```py
s1 = 'MICROSOFT'
s2 = 'CORPS'

for i in range(len(s1) and len(s2)):
    if len(s1)==len(s2):
       var = s1[i] + s2[i]
       print(var , end='')
    elif len(s1)!=len(s2):
        if len(s1)>len(s2):
           var1 = s1[i] + s2[i]
           print(var1, end=' ')

if len(s1) > len(s2):
    print(s1[len(s2):])
elif len(s2) > len(s1):
    print(s2[len(s1):])
```

Comment: @Ab123 I've edited my answer to include the full code. Also note that your code will not work if `len(s2) > len(s1)` because you do not have an `else` for the `if len(s1)>len(s2):` block.

Comment: yes, that's correct, i have not handled that part. because i was just trying the first part only i.e s1>s2